# MySQL WHERE with conditions/priority condtion

Tags: mysql, sql

This one is a weird one that I just can't seem to wrap my head around.

Basically I need to search based on a value that has an override. So there are 2 columns with essentially the same content. One is updated automatically and one is manual. If the automatic one is not available it will use the manual, and if the manual is not available it will use the automatic one. Lastly if both are available it will use the automatic unless and "override" flag is enabled (probably a third column).

What I need to do is search based on that parameter as if it were one field, using the set of priorities on the columns. So here is an example WHERE statement, but I do not know what might be the correct syntax to use.

```
WHERE (isset(width)?(width_override?o_width:width):o_width) = {query}
```

Comment: you should use a stored procedure for this, it will allow you to use variables to store the conditions, which will make it a little easier than trying to do it in a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IF` function.

```
WHERE IF(width IS NOT NULL, IF(width_override, o_width, width),
                            o_width) = {query}
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me errors and since Its different from my knowledge of typical if statements I don't really know where to look to diagnose it.

Comment: @REaction: there's just a comma missing, at the end of the first line. The syntax for the IF() function is simple: `IF(a,b,c)`. IF a is true THEN return b ELSE return c. Barmar just nested another IF expression in place of `b`.

Comment: I see, I will look into that, thanks! With that edit, worked instantly and adds in the override, perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for COALESCE():

```
SELECT COALESCE(overridden_width_col, automatic_width_col) width
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE COALESCE(overridden_width_col, automatic_width_col) = %param
```

COALESCE() will return the first non-NULL parameter. overridden_width_col is set to NULL, it will use automatic_width_col.

Comment: What about the override column?

Comment: o_width is manual, width is automatic. Basically one value is automatically generated by a daemon but to allow more control you can use o_width to override it if need be/ if the automatic one is not set. Lastly the width_override is to force it to use manual regardless.

Comment: @REaction sorry, wasn't clear from the Q. I've clarified my answer

Comment: So far this is working, not "exactly" as intended but Its working in SQL console so I will see how well it translates to the application.